# How to check if a doubly-linked list is properly linked in java?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm implementing an abstract data type for lists of `Coin` objects.
This should be a Doubly-Linked-List

These are the fields:

```
private Coin prev, next; 
private Card head, tail;
private int size;
```

Now, my question is how can I check if the coins are properly linked up in a doubly-linked list.

coondition to check for:

- starting from head, and going through all the elements of the list check if each has a next element/coin.

  - if yes, does that next have a previous?

    - if yes, then it is not null, and must be x. Then, increase x
    - if no, then that's not good!
  - if no(/if there is no next element)...

    - check if length is 1

      - if it is 1, then that,s good!
      - if other, then it is bad!

(All of this should be inside a boolean method with no parameters). This method is just checking if the list is in correct linking format(Doubly linked list)

(This is not a homework question)

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: your question is how to check, and then you immediately follow that with a list of what the check consists of. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot several things:

1. At the start, check to see that `head.prev == null`. (Can't have a node before `head`.)
2. At the start, check to see that `tail.next == null`. (Can't have a node after `tail`.)
3. Keep a count of nodes so that if the count exceeds `size`, the list is not correct.
4. If you reach `tail` and your count is less than `size`, then the list is not correct.
5. If you encounter any node other than `head` that has a null `prev` pointer, then the list is not correct.
6. If you encounter any node other than `tail` that has a null `next` pointer, then the list is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a set to store the iterated Coin. Set iterated = new HashSet();
2. Iterate from HEAD Coin, if the next is not present in the set, check if the next is null, if next is null, then end check, otherwise, check if current == current.next.previous, then put the current coin into the set. otherwise, there is some error in "double linked", you can return false and stop the check.
3. if the next is in the set, then check if the next is the HEAD Coin, if not, then there is a partial loop in the linkedlist (not sure if this is legal or not, but it is a good question to ask). If the next is the HEAD Coin, then it is a looped double linked list, so the previous of HEAD Coin should be the TAIL Coin. otherwise, it is illegal.
4. If you reach null while iteration, then it means there is no LOOP, so previous of HEAD should be NULL.
5. Keep a count while iteration, and check if the count is correct.
6. Check the head and tail accordingly.